# How to retrieve @src with xpath and scrapy if it is svg-xml data?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to retrieve the URL from an image with scrapy, but the page is using svg-xml data for the URL. Within chrome inspector the URL is visible but not in the source code.

They use:

`<img class="main-image" data-product-uid="156597" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20width%3D%22320%22%20height%3D%22320%22%2F%3E" srcset="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20width%3D%22320%22%20height%3D%22320%22%2F%3E" sizes=" (min-width: 1280px) 387px, (min-width: 640px) calc(100vw - 320px) * 50%, 50vw " alt="" data-wa-src="https://www.theirurl.de/tag-heuer/formula-1/quartz-chronograph-43mm-caz1010.ba0842__eb96638ada.png" data-wa-srcset="https://www.theirurl.de/tag-heuer/formula-1/quartz-chronograph-43mm-caz1010.ba0842__7293fe2804.png 640w, https://www.theirurl.de/tag-heuer/formula-1/quartz-chronograph-43mm-caz1010.ba0842__eb96638ada.png 320w">`

Interestingly the data-wa-src image is not the same one.

I am trying to retrieve this main image of the watch: [Example page](https://www.brogle.de/tag-heuer/formula-1/f1-qz-chrono-43/#156597)

Comment: What do you mean by *svg-xml data*? As I can see required image comes with the HTML sample (`<div class="site-702">`) returned by XHR to https://www.brogle.de/ajaxCached/ajax-product-details/paction/showProductAjax/puid/156597/ ... Did you try to simulate this XHR?

Comment: Where did you get this class from? It is not within the source code. I am aiming to retrieve it like e.g. response.xpath('//img[@class="site-702"]/text()').extract()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you requests Product main page such as https://www.brogle.de/tag-heuer/formula-1/f1-auto-smallsecond-43/#156867 your browser makes another request for Product description to https://www.brogle.de/ajaxCached/ajax-product-details/paction/showProductAjax/puid/156867/

Note that Product ID (`156867`) is the only dynamic part of Product description URL, so if you know Product main page URL, you can extract Product ID and send request for description:

*requests + lxml.html example:*

```
import requests
from lxml import html

main_url = "https://www.brogle.de/tag-heuer/formula-1/f1-auto-smallsecond-43/#156867"
api_url = "https://www.brogle.de/ajaxCached/ajax-product-details/paction/showProductAjax/puid/"
product_id = main_url.rsplit("#")[-1]
product_description = requests.get(api_url + product_id).text
html_source = html.fromstring(product_description)
image_src = html_source.xpath('//img[@itemprop="image"]/@src')

print(image_src[0])
#  'https://www.brogle.de/tag-heuer/formula-1/automatic-small-second-43mm-waz2014.ba0842__f4e2ac9b28.png'
```

P.S. Sorry, I don't use Scrapy, but I'm sure that above code can be easily converted to Scrapy code

Comment: Interesting aproach. I also get the URL using python, but even with the other product ID it returns allways the same image which is not the one I am looking for: https://www.brogle.de/tag-heuer/formula-1/quartz-chronograph-43mm-caz1010.ba0842__8a64034690.png

Comment: @merlin , are you sure you've implemented my code correctly? If I change `main_url` to, for instance, https://www.brogle.de/tag-heuer/formula-1/f1-qz-chrono-43/#156521 , I get another (correct) image - https://www.brogle.de/tag-heuer/formula-1/quartz-chronograph-43mm-caz101k.ba0842__290529fadf.png

Comment: I just run it again and received another image, but it is not the high res image I am looking for.: https://www.brogle.de/tag-heuer/formula-1/quartz-chronograph-43mm-caz1010.ba0842__8a64034690.png
https://www.brogle.de/tag-heuer/formula-1/quartz-chronograph-43mm-caz1010.ba0842__bceaf1846c.png Will try to implement this into my scrapy code. Thank you.

Comment: how did you identify the script? I am facing the same issue with another page but can not find a similar script to apply your method. The page parameter here is passed behind a segment identifier and scrapy every time views page 1 regardless of parameter. http://www.rolex.de/de/watches/find-rolex/man.html#g=0&p=2

Comment: @merlin , approaches might be different depending on application... I'd like to see your current code. Do you have SO question for the same?

Comment: Yes, I do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061112/scrapy-linkextractor-ignores-parameters-behind-the-sign-and-thus-will-not-foll